# Machine wide Outlook VSTO add-in missing

Tags: .net, outlook, registry, vsto, outlook-addin

I successfully registered a machine wide Outlook addin, by registering in HKLM locations

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddIn
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddIn
```

But after tinkling around and deleting the key to my addin, I can no longer see it even after re-registering.  It's not listed in "COM Add-ins" nor in disabled add-ins

It only works if I install the addin to the HKCU hive

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddIn
```

On another computer works fine

**Update:**

I am using Wix Toolset to create the MSI, and have full admin on my test machines.  I (loosely) followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022 to create my MSI, it installs and uninstalls fine, and my reg keys are correct

Wix snippet to create reg keys

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="*">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddIn">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="MyAddIn" />
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="FriendlyName" Value="My Add-in" />
      <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="LoadBehavior" Value="00000003" />
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Manifest" Value="file:///[INSTALLFOLDER]MyAddIn.vsto|vstolocal" />
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddIn">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="MyAddIn" />
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="FriendlyName" Value="My Add-in" />
      <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="LoadBehavior" Value="00000003" />
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Manifest" Value="file:///[INSTALLFOLDER]MyAddIn.vsto|vstolocal" />
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="$(var.ProgramFiles)">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductFolder)" />
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

If I (leave everything as is and) only change reg key settings "SOFTWARE\[WOW6432Node\]Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddIn" to "SOFTWARE\[WOW6432Node\]Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\**AnotherAddIn**" Outlook picks up the addin on my machine fine

What I need help understanding is what could cause Outlook to ignore an add-in installed into HKLM.  From above I think we can safely toss out reg key permission issue

Comment: Do you see any other machine-level add-ins on the dialog? Have you tried a newly created sample add-in? Does it work? How do you add windows registry keys to the HKLM hive?

Comment: Can the addin location be accessed by the current user? Are there any errors in the Windows Event log on Outlook startup? Do you see Outlook trying to load your addin on startup in Process Monitor?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev no other machine level addins exist

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I can see the addin loaded in ProcExp when it's registered in HKCU, not when it's in HKLM, no error in Event Log.  Not sure how I'd check with ProcMon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was a noob error, but in case it may be of help to anyone else. In the course of testing and development I ended up with a registration for my add-in in *ClickToRun*, this caused Outlook to not look in HKLM hive for the add-in

The specific location is `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns`

Outlook was able to pick up my add-in after I removed the rogue registration at the above location

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how your add-ins are registered, whether they have enough permissions to add windows registry keys to the HKLM hive. So, I'd suggest creating an add-in installer for that first. The [Deploying a VSTO Solution Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022) article describes all the necessary steps for that.

Comment: I loosely followed that guide since I'm using Wix.  The add-in and payloads are working fine  The only issue is Outlook doesn't see the add-in at all on my pc unless I create a registration in HKCU.  On another pc (using the same user account, works fine

Comment: Something is wrong with your machine then.